# ApplicationController not rescuing Pundit Not Authorized Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, pundit

I'm using Rails 5.2, Pundit 1.1, and rails_admin 1.2

I have the following in my application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I have the following in my application.policy.rb:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
.
.
.
  def rails_admin?(action)
    case action
      when :dashboard
        user.admin?
      when :index
        user.admin?
      when :show
        user.admin?
      when :new
        user.admin?
      when :edit
        user.admin?
      when :destroy
        user.admin?
      when :export
        user.admin?
      when :history
        user.admin?
      when :show_in_app
        user.admin?
      else
        raise ::Pundit::NotDefinedError, "unable to find policy #{action} for #{record}."
    end
  end
end
```

In my config/initializers/rails_admin.rb I have the following:

```
    RailsAdmin.config do |config|
      ### Popular gems integration

      ## == Devise ==
      config.authenticate_with do
        warden.authenticate! scope: :user
      end
      config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

      ## == Pundit ==
      config.authorize_with :pundit

    end

module RailsAdmin
  module Extensions
    module Pundit
      class AuthorizationAdapter
        def authorize(action, abstract_model = nil, model_object = nil)
          record = model_object || abstract_model && abstract_model.model
          if action && !policy(record).send(*action_for_pundit(action))
            raise ::Pundit::NotAuthorizedError.new("not allowed to #{action} this #{record}")
          end
          @controller.instance_variable_set(:@_pundit_policy_authorized, true)
        end

        def authorized?(action, abstract_model = nil, model_object = nil)
          record = model_object || abstract_model && abstract_model.model
          policy(record).send(*action_for_pundit(action)) if action
        end

        def action_for_pundit(action)
          [:rails_admin?, action]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If a user is an admin then they can access the admin dashboard.
However, if a user isn't an admin then they should be redirected to the home page with a flash message.

When I try to access the Rails Admin dashboard for a non-admin user I get the following:
[image]
Why is ApplicationController not rescuing the Pundit::NotAuthorizedError?

I have created a sample app that reproduces this error: https://github.com/helphop/sampleapp

Comment: does putting this config method in your `RailsAdmin.config` block help?
 Make sure you restart your server after adding it. `config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'` - my guess is that RailsAdmin isn't inheriting from your `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I just tried adding config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController' and I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Update —

The error you are actually having involves path helpers — such as `root_url` or `root_path` — inside RailsAdmin. When `rescue_from` encounters an error, it escapes itself.

With that being said, changing the `redirect_to "/"` should solve the problem.

Comment: I tried this and I get the same result as I posted.

Comment: @chell Is this something you could put on GitHub? Or, at the very least, an example app that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I just added a sample app that reproduces this issue.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you for taking the time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'` before `config.authorize_with :pundit`. It will say Rails Admin that RailsAdmin::ApplicationController inherited from your ApplicationController and rescue will work.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your suggestion. I actually had added config.parent_controller = ::ApplicationController before the config.authorize_with :pundit. I have changed it to match your suggestion and it still works. Not sure if there is a difference.